# Iterate throught 3D space without nesting loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I just wrote the code below and thought is there any way to do the same without using the nesting loops and how clean and efficient will it be?

```java
for (int y = Y_LEVEL_START; y <= Y_LEVEL_STOP; y++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIDE; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIDE; x++) {
            if (chunk.getBlock(x, y ,z).getType() == ANCIENT_DEBRIS)
                report.debrisFoundAt(x, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

Comment: @0x5453, oh, I haven't even heard of that, thanks! Though unfortunately, it doesn't fit my problem — I just don't see a way of putting the right chunk blocks into an octree without using the same 3d loop :D